# Refactor a project to use a different SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, chromium-embedded, awesomium

I'm working on an old WPF application that uses an Awesomium core and some other functions to output few HTML based pages. The application won't start because few pages are referencing Awesomium (which doesn't exist) and I figured there's no point for me to attempt to make it work as I'm not familiar with this kit anyways. I am looking to refactor the application to use something like Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF). What would be the best way to achieve that?

For some clarification, there is a web interface already built within the project, and Awesomium is referenced and used in roughly 10-20 pages.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Please take a look at [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Questions should be formatted in this way as generic questions such as this will normally be closed.